# Read Sharepoint List Value using javascript and set to variable

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I feel I have a fairly simple problem but every solution online is seriously complicated. I am in SharePoint designer 2010 and I am not a programmer but I can get by. I have a SP list with Contract Numbers and when you click the contract number it brings you to the item. I just want JavaScript code that will read the value from the list (by ID or however) and store it in a variable.

For example:

```
var siteUrl = 'https://...';
var itemID = 22;
var TargetListItem;
Function onLoad(){
var context = new SP.ClientContent(siteUrl);
var web = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Data Call');
var list = web.getItemById(itemID);
context.load(list, 'Contract Number');

var value = list.get_item('Contract Number');

var url = "/sites/... " + value + "...";
return url
}
```

The code works if I hard-code value so that the URL returned has a parameter, but not when I set value above.  Please if anyone has a really simple way to accomplish this let me know!

Comment: Maybe the answer is complicated....  Try to go back to those solutions and see if they will work for you.  If they do, get to reading and see if you can figure them out.  If anything is really throwing you for a loop, ask about it here if and only if you can't find the answer anywhere else and it fits the site's question standards.  Right now, you're simply asking for code, which doesn't usually work well out well.  Try posting what you've tried and why it didn't work as part of your question, and the answers you get will be better (and more likely to happen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907%28v=office.15%29.aspx) that *executes the current pending request asynchronously on the server*

[SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907%28v=office.15%29.aspx) has the following signature:

```
SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeededCallback, failedCallback)
```

and since it is **async** method you cant return from your method, but have to declare `succeededCallback` function that contains the returned results.

When working with asynchronous API such as JSOM the following patterns are commonly used:

- Using nested callbacks
- Using the promises pattern

Please refer [Asynchronous programming in apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220067%28v=office.15%29.aspx) article to get acquainted with asynchronous programming for SharePoint.

The below example demonstrates how to get list item using callback approach:

```
function getItem(listTitle,itemId,success,error){  
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = context.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var listItem = list.getItemById(itemId);
   context.load(listItem);

   context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
        success(listItem);
   },
   error
  );
}
```

Example

```
getItem('Data Call', 22,
  function(item){
       var result = item.get_item('Contract Number'); 
  },
  function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

### References

[How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Asynchronous programming in apps for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220067%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: @Vadim : Do you have any idea for  call window.open(result) inside the success function